# I can't completely clear the transformed rectangle in <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

This code can't completely clear the transformed rectangle in canvas element.
How can i completely clear?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.transform(1, 0.5, 0, 1, canvas.width / 2 , canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(20, 20, 200, 100);
context.clearRect(20, 20, 200, 100);
```

I can clear transformed rectangle by following code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x = 20;
var y = 20;
var width = 200;
var height = 100;

context.transform(1, 0.5, 0, 1, canvas.width / 2 , canvas.height / 2);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
context.clearRect(x, y - 1, width, height + 2);
```

I move up clear rectangle to top 1px and increase 2px wide to clear remaining border.

This code works well. But it is short term solution!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this as well. This is caused by the anti-aliasing which is applied to the initial shape. It works with shapes which do not use anti-aliasing, such as rectangles when you don't transform your canvas.
The only solution I found is to call `clearRectangle` with a shape that is slightly taller (about 1-2 pixels each side).