# Canvas transform rotation artifacts

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transform, image-rotation

I got this little code that makes a simple image rotate

```js
var img = new Image(50, 200);
img.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  setInterval(function() {
    main.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
    main.getContext("2d").rotate(-1 * Math.PI / 180);
    main.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 200, 0, 0, 50, 200);
  }, 50);
});
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCWW9.png";
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="main" width=600 height=400></canvas>
</body>
```

The linked rectangle image resource : 
[image: the rectangle image resource]

The result : [image]

Why does it generate all these artifacts?

Comment: Don't know why exactly, but if you do `main.getContext("2d").clearRect(-1, -1, 600, 400);` it works fine.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I found out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21905707

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found out the problem, it appears that the transform matrix also have effect on the clearRect() method so the "clearing area" is rotated as well...

Just had to add setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) that resets the transform matrix before calling clearRect() like so:

```js
var rotation=0;
var img = new Image(50, 200);
    img.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
        setInterval(function() {
        rotation--;
        main.getContext("2d").setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);         //that line was missing
        main.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
        main.getContext("2d").rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
        main.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 200, 0, 0, 50, 200);
        }, 50);
});
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCWW9.png";
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="main" width=600 height=400></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Just note that `resetTransform()` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/resetTransform#Browser_compatibility) in all browsers, You can use `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` instead. I would advice caching the context to a variable.

Comment: thanks for the compatibility info ! I edit my answer with your method

Answer (score 0):

Based on @GolfWolf's comment I use the following code it works.

```js
var img = new Image(50, 200);
img.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  setInterval(function() {
    main.getContext("2d").clearRect(-0.5, -0.5, 600, 400);
    main.getContext("2d").rotate(-1 * Math.PI / 180);
    main.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 200, 0, 0, 50, 200);
  }, 50);
});
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCWW9.png";
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="main" width=600 height=400></canvas>
</body>
```